# Working with src and alt to replace an image

Tags: javascript, php, html, src, alt

I have a part in my site that dedicated to changing the language. 
Right now, in a circle button, i have united-kingdom flag. This is the default option.

```
  <a class="nav-link-language  js-language-trigger">
    <img src="http://my-site.test/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/260-united-kingdom.png" alt="">
```

For example i have an option for German Language

```
    <div class="nav-link-language-holder">
      <a><img src="http://my-site.test/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/260-germany.png" alt=""><i>German</i></a>
    </div>
```

How can i set with javscript, when user click on the icon for Germany, it will be replaced for the default option (right now is united-kingdom)

Thanks a lot

Comment: What have you tried ?!

Comment: What do you mean by default option? What exactly do you want to replace on your site? The src of your <img> tag in the class "nav-link-language-holder"?

Comment: Is your page reloading when the user clicks the icon for Germany? If so, you should handle the `src` when rendering the page. If not, then add an `event listener` for `click` and have it run a little javascript to change the icon.

Comment: As an aside; flags aren't a good way represent language - especially in places like Belgium or Luxembourg.

Comment: @DanielBürckner i mean by default option is the image that set on the button for changing language. I want it to change when i click on another options (for example when i click on the Germany flag, it goes to be default

Comment: You can try this link [ https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FSSCNQXNIDOE ]

Comment: @MrGlass Thanks for your help, no the site won't be refreshed. Could you give me a sample of the way  you said? Thanks a lot

Comment: @NileshSutar this link is not working

Comment: @R.Davis, we would have to see the code that runs when a user clicks on the icon for Germany.

Comment: Check now I have edited the link

Comment: Are you willing to change only the flag or the whole language for that active session ?

Comment: @Abdenn0ur Just only the flag for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick way to change your img src :

```
<img id="Your_IMG_ID" src="olg-img-src.png">
<button onclick="change_img_src()">Change SRC</button>
<script>
function change_img_src() {
    document.getElementById("Your_IMG_ID").src = "new-img-src.png";
}
</script>
```

To generalize what you're looking for and further simplify it, here's a way to do it :

```
<!--- Your main flag --->
<img id="main-flag" style="cursor:pointer" src="img.png"/>

<!--- Rest of flags --->
<img style="cursor:pointer" onclick="Change_flag(this.src)" src="img.png"/>
<img style="cursor:pointer" onclick="Change_flag(this.src)" src="img-2.png"/>
<img style="cursor:pointer" onclick="Change_flag(this.src)" src="img-3.png"/>
<!----Other flags---->
<script>
function Change_flag(_src) {
    document.getElementById("main-flag").src = _src;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You are welcome :) you can get rid of that button and make your img a button itself, and perform other things like changing the language cookie inside the js code. good luck playing with your script :D

Comment: It works great, thanks. But just a question. i already have the adress of png file in my html, I dont want to write again on the javascript file, can you change your code in this way?

Comment: @AbdennOur  this part i mean: .src = "new-img-src.png";

Comment: I'll see what i can do, for my understanding, you need to to get the source of the the already shown flags and replace them to your main (default) flag right ?